Is there a max limit to PyArrow write_dataset row-group sizes
Question:  is there some internally imposed upper limit on the min_rows_per_group parameter of pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset?
I have a number of parquet files that I am trying to coalesce into larger files with larger row-groups.
With write_dataset (doesn't work as expected)
To do so, I am iterating over the files and using pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.iter_batches to yield record batches, which form the input to pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset.  I would like to write row-groups of ~9 million.
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

def batch_generator():
    source = UPath(INPATH)
    for f in source.glob('*.parquet'):
        with pq.ParquetFile(f) as pf:
            yield from pf.iter_batches(batch_size=READ_BATCH_SIZE)

batches = batch_generator()
ds.write_dataset(
        batches, 
        OUTPATH, 
        format='parquet',
        schema=SCHEMA,
        min_rows_per_group=WRITE_BATCH_SIZE,
        max_rows_per_group=WRITE_BATCH_SIZE,
        existing_data_behavior='overwrite_or_ignore'
    )

Notes:

UPath is from universal-pathlib and is basically the equivalent of pathlib.Path but works for both local as well as cloud storage.
WRITE_BATCH_SIZE is set to ~9.1M
READ_BATCH_SIZE is a smaller value, ~ 12k, to lower memory footprint while reading.

When I check my output (using pyarrow.parquet.read_metadata) I see that I have a single file (as desired) but row-groups are no larger than ~2.1M.
Alternative approach (works)
I then tried this alternative approach to coalescing the row-groups (adapted from this gist):
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

def batch_generator():
    source = UPath(INPATH)
    for f in source.glob('*.parquet'):
        with pq.ParquetFile(f) as pf:
            yield from pf.iter_batches(batch_size=READ_BATCH_SIZE)

def write_parquet(outpath: UPath, tables):
    with pq.ParquetWriter(outpath, SCHEMA) as writer:
        for table in tables:
            writer.write_table(table, row_group_size=WRITE_BATCH_SIZE)

def aggregate_tables():
    tables = []
    current_size = 0
    for batch in batch_generator():
        table = pa.Table.from_batches([batch])
        this_size = table.num_rows
        if current_size + this_size > WRITE_BATCH_SIZE:
            yield pa.concat_tables(tables)
            tables = []
            current_size = 0
        tables.append(table)
        current_size += this_size
    if tables:
        yield pa.concat_tables(tables)

write_parquet(OUTPATH, aggregate_tables(), SCHEMA)

batch_generator remains the same as before.  The key difference here is that I am manually combining row-groups issued by batch_generator, using pa.concat_tables().
My output file has one row-group of ~9M, and a second row-group of ~3M, which is what I expect and want.
So my question is... why does pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset not write up to the requested value of min_rows_per_group but seem to cap off at ~2.1M?
